# how to set fill width and custom height in layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I would like to set my image view to fixed height and fill width.

to do this,I selected my image view and :

[image]

after above constraints, I click on "selected view > update constraint on constants" but when I change preview screen size, it doesn't show good :

[image]

where is my wrong ?

Comment: Set your imageView contentMode as `AspectFit`

Comment: I don't use IB that much, but I think your okay. Look to me like after changing the screen size, you didn't update the frames.

Comment: You need to  **update frame** instead of *update constraint on constants*

Comment: You need to update all views frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update frame, not constraint constants:

[image]